# Changing the band for contour lines?

Tags: qgis, contour, netcdf, mapping

I am making contour lines for a NetCDF file for sea surface temperature and the contour lines display the first band only (bands represents different dates). Theres few 100 bands in the NetCDF, how do I make sure the contour lines match the band I want?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I found the answer!

Here is the process:
Raster->Extraction->Contour

In the pop up box go to gdal_contour and right after 'gdal_contour' add '-b #' where # is the band number you want.

It was in the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html)

Hope this helps someone else!